# Can I use client certificate generated in API Gateway to validate at Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, certificate, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created self client certificate within API Gateway. I would like my lambda to validate before processing the request from API Gateway (Configure Backend to Authenticate API).

API Gateway allows us to copy the certificate to clipboard. Which we can save as var or file to be read within Nodejs Lambda function, authenticate and proceed further.

Do we have examples?

Answer (score 4):

API Gateway is invoking your AWS Lambda function via the the Lambda Invoke method in the AWS API. Your Lambda function isn't a web server, so it isn't receiving a direct HTTPS request from API Gateway, so it isn't going to receive the HTTPS client certificate.

I would question the need for this anyway. Your API Gateway should be using an IAM role to invoke the Lambda function. That's the mechanism you would use to make sure only API Gateway has access to invoke your Lambda function. The client-certificate is for web servers running behind API Gateway that don't use IAM for authentication.

Comment: Mark - Okay. So what does configure your backend api mean?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html#certificate-validation

Comment: It means if you are pointing API Gateway to a backend sever on EC2 or something like that, then you can configure the server software to validate the client certificate. That's a completely different API Gateway integration method than the one you would be using to trigger Lambda function execution.

Comment: Client certificates are for `HTTP` integration type,  which is needed lock down a public HTTP API so that only API Gateway can call it. You don't need that method of locking down AWS Lambda since the Lambda function itself isn't public and your IAM permissions ensure that only API Gateway can invoke it. Note how at the top of the page you linked it says "This allows your HTTP backend to control and accept only requests originating from Amazon API Gateway". It is only for HTTP backends, not Lambda.

Comment: @Mark B I think the question (if I am reading it correctly) is geared more towards achieving an mTLS (Mutual TLS) with API gateway using Lambda Authorizer. In this case the client program (web or mobile app) would make a call to the API with a Client Cert which would then need to be verified by the Lambda Authorizer (in addition to traditional API key and what not). It's surprising that AWS API Gateway still has no support for mTLS for Clients. It only supports backend cert validations which is what you are saying.

Comment: @Annjawn I get exactly what you are saying, and I agree that would be a nice feature that Amazon should add to API Gateway, but that's not what this specific question is about. At least, that's not what the feature referenced in the question designed for. API Gateway allows you to a create certificate and perform certificate validation between the API and an HTTP backend, which is the feature being referred to in the question.